# How can I eliminate the noise in this case?

Tags: noise

As a part of a big system Arduino is being affected from a switch outside(so the spike is not always there only when an outside switch or surge happens ect.) and I guess through its USB producing spikes on its output. Arduino is set normally to output around 40Hz pulse train and when the spike hits it upsets the Device it couples to below:

[image]

I dont have enough time to figure out all the system and block whats happening. I rather want to eliminate or filter the spike which looks like below:

[image]

I have a scope screenshot but it is not very good one that's why I draw it above. But anyway below is the screenshot the pink one is the pulse signal.

You can see the spike above during the pulse ON time.

How can I eliminate this spike? Would a low pass filter, zener didoe or an opto-isolator help? Is there a topology at the output of the pulse signal from Arduino I can try out? A such topology drawn circuit would help in an answer.

And here are how the 12VDC 5VDC power supplies and a 10VAC step down 10step down transformer is affected by the switch in the same system:

**Edit:**

I treied to simulate the spike and use an RC and a schmitt trigger with hysteresis as suggested:

[image]

Signals at input, output and comparator's inverting and non-inverting terminals:

[image]

I put R6 C5 to suppress the spike in the system to not to upset comparator, is that a fine way to filter the spike from Vcc? What do you think about the circuit?

Comment: An opto-coupler wouldn't be a bad idea. Then if the spike is still there, a (indeed low-pass) filter with a cut-off frequency high enough not to influence your measurements and low enough to catch the spike. The Zener diode before the filter also isn't a bad idea to remove a large part of the energy in the pulse.

Comment: Your pulse is about 100 microSeconds. If your data rate is SLOW (40 Hz), thus place 300 microsecond timeconstant Low Pass Filter at the receiver end; use 330 ohms and 1uF ceramic. Tie the cap from GND to the input pin, right at the receiver. How long is the cable between the two hardware modules?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf 1 meter

Comment: @analogsystemsrf All comes from AC mains(through  asurge or switch) and I was unable to stop it tried everything even an isolation transformer ect. So I only want to eliminate that spike which upsets the other unit. I will try RC filter thanks.

Comment: If this is electric-field induced, then a shielded cable should help. If this is magnetic-field induced,then TWISTED PAIR should help. And we are taught that a coax cable will also help, for both EFI and HFI. Now you have to decide how to tie the shield: floating? at transmitter end? at receiver end? at both ends? If you use shielded twisted-pair (some audio cables are like this), I'd tie the shield to BOTH ends, because you clearly already have a GND/RETURN wire running between the TX and Rx.

Comment: Unless you need precise timing, increase the capacitor to 10uF. This provides another 10:1 filtering of the pulse, at cost of making the desired signal's risetime 10X slower. Does the Arduino have hysteresis on the Receiver Pin? Is that softrware controlled? You may need to add an external Hysteresis IC in the signal path, RIGHT AT THE ARDUINO. Consider a hex Schmidt SN7414 inverter. Use 2 of the inverters in series, to preserve signal polarity. Again, you will have lots of delay, if you use the RC filter to absorb energy.

Comment: To best reject magnetic fields, have the signal-return (2 wires) be as close as possible and TWISTED, at least several turns per inch, so the voltage induced by magnetic flux will be more self-cancelling. Use professional TwistedPair; homemade is OK to try out the effect, but the irregularity of the homemade twists does not give best attenuation of the induced voltage. Notice you'll get attenuation, not total cancellation.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf How about an optoisoaltor/coupler right before the receiver?

Comment: The interferer is already huge. Assuming this is not Ground_Upset, without some shielding, you will create a well-isolated signal with a hole in the middle from the interference.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Please see my edit. I did what you suggested in simulation. But have some more questions regarding power supply filtering and the circuit. I would be glad to have your feedback.

Comment: @ User Do your best to have all FIVE of those capacitors tied to the same small region of Ground (1cm square) if you can. This gives best rejection of magnetic fields. I like the circuit and the Power Supply filtering. You could go for more hysteresis; increase the 3.3K to 10K; this moves the 2 trip points up, and moves them apart, for better noise immunity.